# Не отображаются модули prestashop

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. При переходе на сайте на русский язык, все модули перестают отображаться и сайт в целом начинает работать не корректно. Так же не работает поиск. Плюс к этому, тема вообще не переводится на русский язык. Возвращаясь на английскую версию, сайт работает, все модули не месте. 
В чем же может быть заложена проблема? Ведь в английской версии все отлично отображается.